# помогите выдает ошибку

Tags: python

```
Python/Python312/python.exe" не распознано как имя командлета,
функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы.
Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:3
Python312/python.exe c: ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (A...n312/python.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Ну так вы питон, наверное, не установили. Или установили не туда, куда прописываете. Проверьте. Да и команду, возможно, неправильную вводите.

Comment: Что помочь? Понять, что там написано?

Comment: а файлы нужно вставлять писать туда где лежит сам питон?

Comment: Кто выдаёт ошибку то? Что вы запускаете и где?

Comment: Если вы запускаете команду `Python/Python312/python.exe` (судя по ошибке), то так он не будет работать. Можно попробовать просто `python`, например.

Answer (score -1):

Либо у тебя в PATH нет python.
И через powershell нужно писать если ты в папке с программой .\python.exe
(Постарайтесь не задавать такие вопросы)

Comment: Постарайтесь не давать ответы на такие вопросы. Отвечать нужно на вопросы, соответствующие нормам сайта.